# Mongodb grouping statement by custom file

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to retrieve data from mongodb, grouping and summing for a custom field based in a db field which can exist or not but I don't have the result I expect because I there is no data ggrupation (see attached file)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSPQR.png). The mongo statement is:

```
aggregate({

$match: {
    owner: 'W99999',
        creation_date: {
            $gte: 1530748800,
            $lte: 1531292133
        }
    },
$project: {

  isWarm: { 
    $cond: [{
        $not: ["$referral"] }, 1, 0 ]
  },

  isCold: { 
    $cond: [{
        $not: ["$referral"] }, 0, 1 ]
  },

        daysBefore: {
            $subtract: [6, {
                $trunc: {
                    $divide: [{
                        $subtract: ['$creation_date', 1530748800]
                    }, 86400]
                }
            }]
        }
},
$group: {
  _id: {
            isWarm: { $sum: "$isWarm" },
            isCold: { $sum: "$isCold" },
            daysBefore: '$daysBefore'
        }
})
```

I think the problem is the "isWarm" and "isCold" condition for creating them. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE 05/07/2018.**

- Schema (trunked for security reasons):

  ```
  { 
    "_id": "1",  
    "creation_date":"1515780901",  
    "referral:  //This field is optional. 
     { 
         some_data: { }
     },  
      more_data: { } 
  }
  ```
- Result expected:

  ```
  { [
      { isCold: 3, isWarm: 2, daysBefore: 0 }, 
      { isCold: 2, isWarm: 5, daysBefore: 1 }, 
      { isCold: 5, isWarm: 0, daysBefore: 2 }, 
      { isCold: 1, isWarm: 2, daysBefore: 3 }, 
      { isCold: 1, isWarm: 1, daysBefore: 4 }, 
      { isCold: 1, isWarm: 0, daysBefore: 5 },    
      { isCold: 0, isWarm: 0, daysBefore: 6 }   
  ] }
  ```

I would like to have the object even if there is no documents to count (e.g. last line of the result).

**RESOLVED:** I need to test with real data.

- I think I have a solution:

  ```
  [{ $project: {  
  _id: 0,  
  daysBefore: {           
      $subtract: [6, {                
          $trunc: {                   
              $divide: [{                     
                  $subtract: ['$creation_date', 1530748800] }, 86400]
          }
      }]
  },
  isWarm: {$cond: [{ $gte: ['$referral', null]}, 1, 0]},  
  isCold: {$cond: [{ $gte: ['$referral', null]}, 0, 1]}} }, 

  { 
      $group: 
          { 
              _id: { creation_date: '$daysBefore' },
              isWarm: { $sum: '$isWarm' },
              isCold: { $sum: '$isCold' }
          } 
  }]
  ```

Comment: Can you please add the data (documents) for the query with expected response to the post ? Also, explain the daysBefore usage in the group stage in relation to isWarm and isCold field.

Comment: please post your sample collection please... You have posted your expected output... And please post it in your question by updating it